# How to do custom permission check for nested serializer with nested models having different permission in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm building a webapp, where a user can create a team and add members and his/her projects. Everything is working fine, but now comes the permission part. One model will be `Team` and another `Project`. Right now i have written custom permission for both the models extending `BasePermission`.

The operation/permission would be :

1. User1 created a team `Team1`, can add any members and add his projects (no permission to add others project)
2. members of `Team1` can add their own projects and edit (CRU) projects added by others. No permission for the members to delete Team1, only creator can delete the team.
3. A project can only be edited by the members of the team to which it is added. Others cannot. Only creator of the project can delete it.

**Permissions:**

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from .models import Team,Project
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProjectPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to perform this action with Project that doesn't belong to you or you are not a member of the team for this Project"
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request,view, obj):
        if not request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            if request.method != "DELETE":
                if obj.team: #Team can be null when creating a project
                    return obj.created_by == request.user or request.user in obj.team.members.all() 
                return obj.created_by == request.user
            return obj.created_by == request.user
        return request.user.is_authenticated
        
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_authenticated

class TeamPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to perform this action with Team that is not created by you or you are not a member with full permission"
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return request.user.is_authenticated
        else:
            if request.method != "DELETE":
                if obj.created_by == request.user or request.user in obj.members.all():
                    return True
            return obj.created_by == request.user
    
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            
            if request.method =="DELETE":
                return True
            Projects = request.data.get('Projects')
            if request.method =="PUT" or request.method == "PATCH":
                if len(Projects)==0:return True # for removing a list projects an empty array is passed, in the serializer set function "remove set(current projects - empty list)" is used to identify the projects to remove 
            if Projects:
                perm = []
                for Project in Projects:
                    try:
                         #this is the issue, if there are 100 projects to be added, it does 100 queries to fetch the object
                        perm.append(ProjectPermission().has_object_permission(request, view,Project.objects.get(id=Project)))
                    except Exception as e:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError(e)
                if False in perm:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(
                        {"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action with Project that doesn't belong to you or you are not a member of the team for this Project"})           
                return True
        else:
            return request.user.is_authenticated
```

This line at the end causes 100 queries to db for 100 projects. i can do filter in by project list. but is there any alternatives ?

```
perm.append(ProjectPermission().has_object_permission(request, view,Project.objects.get(id=Project))
```

**Views:**

```
class ProjectView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    Returns a list of all the Projects. created by user and others
    Supports CRUD
    '''
    queryset=Project.objects.select_related('team','created_by').all()
    serializer_class=ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes=[ProjectPermission]

class TeamView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Returns a list of all the teams. created by user and others
    Supports CRUD
    """
    queryset=Team.objects.prefetch_related('members','projects').select_related('created_by').all()
    serializer_class=TeamSerializer
    permission_classes=[TeamPermission]
```

**models:**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False,unique=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    members=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='members')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.team_name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-created_at']
     
class Project(models.Model):
    team=models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='projects',blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    project_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False,unique=True)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True,blank=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.project_name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve what i need ? I read about adding permission in the models, but i have no idea how it can be done in this case. Any suggestion would be a great help

Comment: Could you add your `models` to the question?

Comment: @MohamedHamza updated question with the models

Comment: @MohamedHamza were you able to check it?

Comment: Yes, I checked it

Comment: If I understand, any `User` can create a `Team`, and team members can **CRU** the project, and only the team owner can delete the project, is that right?

Comment: Last part wasn't right. Team should be deleted by team owner and project should be deleted by project owner, no one else. Also only the owner of the project can add it to a team, if he is a member in that team...then the other members can RU that project

Comment: Is django no longer anyone's favourite? I dont see any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down, any `User` can create a `Team` so there is one permission `IsAuthenticated`

Any `Team` member can **CRU** a Project so there are three permissions here:

`IsAuthenticated` & ( `IsTeamOwner` | `IsTeamMember`)

for deleting a Project, there are two permission (`IsAuthenticated` & `IsProjectOwner`) and so on so forth

so, the permissions could be something like that:

```py
class IsTeamOwner(BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to perform this action"

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.created_by == request.user


class IsProjectOwner(BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to perform this action"

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.created_by == request.user


class IsTeamMember(BasePermission):
    message = "You do not have permission to perform this action"

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user in obj.members.all()
```

**Update**

To check if the project `id` exists and is created by the current user or not:

```py
try: 
    project = Project.objects.only('team').get(id=recieved_id, created_by=request.user)
except Project.DoesNotExist:
    raise ProjectNotExist() # Create this exception
```

To check if the project `id` exists and belongs to the team that the current user is in or not:

```py
try: 
    project = Project.objects.get(id=recieved_id).select_related('team')# try to use prefetch_related('team__members') also, I don't know it would work or not 
    if request.user not in project.team.members.all():
        raise ProjectNotExist() 
except Project.DoesNotExist:
    raise ProjectNotExist()
```

and for more customization, after you checked if the project exists or not you could use `bulk_update` to update the `team` field in every project with only one query.

Comment: Thank you Hamza. But How can i add separate permission for deleting? Also as i mentioned a team member can add only his projects to the team, and edit others added project..so adding and removing projects, the data will be passed as a list of project id's, so how will has_object_permission work in that scenario?

Comment: First of all `ModelViewSet` wouldn't be a good choice in your case, causes there is business logic and validation you have to do and you need to control over the flow so I suggest using `APIView` with `serializers.Serializer` and every `CRUD` endpoint have it's own business logic and validation, this is your 1st question.

Comment: For the 2nd question, you would have an endpoint like `AddProjectsToTemaApi` that received a list of project id's so you need to check if the project `id` exists or not and created by the current user, I called that `validation` not `permissions` and if the `id` does not exist then raise an exception, I would update my answer of that.

Comment: Thank you Hamza for the detailed explanation. But with the modelviewset, i can control the validations in view or in serializer. during team creation or updating, the projects can be added with one api call in my scenario. but if i use AddProjectsToTemaApi  , it will be 2 api calls for creating and updating. any suggestion on that ? i have upvoted, let me try your solution, i will accept if it passes the test

Comment: Also the issue here is that when a list of projects are passed for updating(any member of a team can update any project in that team), the permission needs to be checked for each project, right now this makes n queries to check permission. will that be solved with IsTeamMember permission ?

Comment: Take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide) for organizing the endpoints.
Do you need to check if the current user belongs to the team that belongs to the current project?

Comment: No..lets say im creating a team, i will be passing team name and projects. Where projects is a list. Now i can calidate whether the project in projects list belongs to the one sent request or not..but i want to set it up in permission. So it will check if the current user has permission for the projects in the list which he sent for creating team

Comment: The team is a portion of the project, not vice versa! 
Creating a new team means the current user is the owner of the team, so all we need to check if every project in the project list belongs to that user or not via `IsProjectOwner` that I mentioned before